# Group based on multiple rows and columns

Tags: linux, awk

An example of the data is as follows. The first two columns are IDs and the third column is the frequency.

```
1 2 99
2 3 62
4 5 80
4 4 98
5 5 79
6 1 98
```

The first and second columns are the same person or duplicated IDs. For example, 1, 2, 3 and 6 are the same person. 1==3 since 1==2 & 2==3 and so on. Therefore, data can be split like this.

person 1

```
1 2 99
2 3 62
6 1 98
```

person 2

```
4 5 80
4 4 98
5 5 79
```

How can I split the data as above? Here comparisons have to be made across rows. This is the confusing part for me.
Then, among each group, I would like to select the IDs based on the frequency in the third column. Here I get the animals with the lowest frequency to eliminate those IDs from another file.
The preferred final output is as follows.

```
2 3 62
6 1 98
4 5 80
5 5 79
```

I searched for an answer but for me, this seems complicated. Maybe there is a better way of doing rather than splitting the data. Any ideas, please.

Comment: based on what you will know 1,2,3 and 6 are one person and 4,5 are another person? if first&second columns were the same then they are another person (but this `4 5 80
` line violated this role)? and if col1!=col2 all are the another person? and assuming that, now here there are 3persons?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. 4 and 5 are the same person, since 4==5 in line 3 of original data.

Comment: I still don't get you, how `1 2` and others combination could be person1 but then `4 5` could be person2? how you know `4 5` is person2 not person1? and then later in `6 1` it's becoming person1 again?!

Comment: I suppose, the third column is frequency? And you want the two lowest frequencies, but not sorted? And are there always just two persons? And you alwys want the two lowest rows? So many open questions …

Comment: @αғsнιη This is the structure of the data. I am confused too.

Comment: @Philippos Third column is frequency. I want to get the lowest, but the lowest or highest is acceptable. It is okay to sort.

Comment: I understand how columns 1 and 2 are IDs and how they group to a person, but I do not follow how you select on column3 for the desired output: there are only 2 persons sot the output should only have 2 entries if it was about min (or max) value of column 3 for an individual. Yet you have two per person?

Comment: @FelixJN Thanks. Question edited. Minimum or max would be okay too. The main problem for me to figure out is how to split based on matching ID.

Comment: Why is `4 5 80` part of the final output and not `4 4 98` which is the largest percentage for the second group/person/animal (and `5 5 79` is the smallest for the same group)?

Comment: @they - it looks like the target is to determine the highest frequency value for a unique person, then remove the respective entry. So person1 has `1 2 99` removed and person 2 `4 4 98`. OP: please check the formulation of your question. It has minimum mentioned but maximum removed!

Comment: You have 2 different questions in your question - a) how to split the input by person, and b) how to select IDs based on frequency. You should ask question "a" here, get an answer for it, try to solve your second problem by building on that answer, and THEN ask question "b" as a new question if you still need help afterwards.

Comment: If you can have input like `1 2 99\n3 4 98\n3 1 97`, i.e. where you don't know when you first see `3` that it will later become associated with `1` then you should include that in your example as that's a harder problem to solve than the cases covered by your input right now where every ID has always previously been associated with an existing ID or is a new person - it's never a new ID that's **later** associated with an existing ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing just your first question: Here's how to split the input as you want using any awk+sort in any bourne-derived shell on every Unix box (I'm using bash in my shebang but it doesn't need to be bash):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '{ print $0 ORS $2, $1, $3 }' "${@:--}" |
sort -n -k1,1 -k2,2 |
awk '
    !seen[($1 > $2 ? $1 FS $2 : $2 FS $1)]++ {
        out = ""

        for ( i=1; i<=2; i++ ) {
            if ( $i in map ) {
                out = map[$i]
                break
            }
        }

        if ( out == "" ) {
            out = "person_" (++numPeople)
        }

        for ( i=1; i<=2; i++ ) {
            map[$i] = out
        }

        print >> out
        close(out)
    }
'
```

We need to modify your posted sample input to contain lines as described in [my comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/686666/group-based-on-multiple-rows-and-columns/686679?noredirect=1#comment1298038_686666) to really test that the splitting works:

```
$ cat file
1 2 99
2 3 62
4 5 80
4 4 98
5 5 79
6 1 98
7 8 99
9 10 98
9 7 97
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
```

```
$ head person*
==> person_1 <==
1 2 99
1 6 98
2 3 62

==> person_2 <==
4 4 98
4 5 80
5 5 79

==> person_3 <==
7 8 99
7 9 97
9 10 98
```

The above assumes that the order of the first 2 IDs in each line doesn't matter because `1 2 x` is equivalent to `2 1 x`.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer for the "splitting the data"-part only. It uses the GNU-`awk` feature [arrays of arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays-of-Arrays.html) so is a `gawk`-solution only.

It groups by overlapping IDs from column 1 and 2 and gives each person a unique ID, then prints to files called `person_ID`:

```
gawk '
#id=array of arrays with unique ids UID and alias
#IDs aID as taken from the file: id[UID][aID]

#manually create first entry in line 1
NR==1 { id[1][$1]=1 ; id[1][$2]=1 ; next }

#on other input: scan array id for a match in aIDs
#use related UID it if match is found
FNR==NR {
  for (i=1 ; i<=length(id) ; i++ ) {
    if ($1 in id[i] || $2 in id[i] ) {
      id[i][$1]=i ; id[i][$2]=i ; next }
  }
#if no match was found, create a new UID:
  new=length(id)+1
  id[new][$1]=new ; id[new][$2]=new
}

#rerun through id arrays to check for doubles:
FNR!=NR && !b {
  for ( i in id ) {
    for ( j in id[i] ) {
      if ( seen[j] ) {
        for ( k in id[i] ) { id[seen[j]][k]=id[seen[j]][k] }
        delete id[i]
        }
       else { seen[j]=i }
    }
  }
  delete seen
#adjust UIDs as they may be out of order now to new id array nid,
#delete old id array:
  for ( i in id ) {++n ; for (j in id[i]) { nid[n][j]=id[i][j] } }
  delete id
  b=!b
}

#write to separate files per UID
FNR!=NR {
  for (i in nid) {
    if ($1 in nid[i] || $2 in nid[i] ) { print > "person_"i }
  }
}

#This is just to print the aID vs UID map
END {
  for (i in nid) {
    print "aIDs for person UID=",i ; b=1
    for (j in nid[i]) {
      if (b) {printf j ; b=0}
      else {printf ","j}
    }
  print ""
  }
}
' infile infile
```

Now for your problem of eliminating the lines, I'd suggest this very simple approach:

Make use of the files `person_i` as created above and select the lines with minimum value in field 3 for each file. Write those lines to a `delete_me` file and use an inverted grep on the original file:

```
for file in person_* ; do
  sort -n -k3 ${file} | head -n1
done > delete_me
grep -xvf delete_me original
```

Minumum selection is done by `sort` only so no refinement when it comes to identical numbers or alike. Use `-x` for `grep` to ensure that the match must be covering exactly the whole line (otherwise `1 2 3` would match `1 2 3` and e.g. `1 2 33`)

---

The following variation will just group the persons by id and sieve out the line with maximum in column 3 for a unique person. In the second read of the input file, only lines without these maximum lines are printed - so this is the one-script solution without extra files:

```
#id=array of arrays with unique ids UID and alias
#IDs aID as taken from the file: id[UID][aID]

#manually create first entry in line 1, print to "person_1"
NR==1 { id[1][$1]=1 ; id[1][$2]=1 ; next }
#manually create first entry for line deletion selection
NR==1 { max[1]=$3 ; line[1]=$0 }

#on other input: scan array id for a match in aIDs
#use related UID it if match is found
FNR==NR {
  for (i=1 ; i<=length(id) ; i++ ) {
    if ($1 in id[i] || $2 in id[i] ) {
      id[i][$1]=i ; id[i][$2]=i
#select line for deletion
      if ($3>=max[i]) { max[i]=$3 ; line[i]=$0 }
      ; next
    }
  }
#if no match was found, create a new UID:
  new=length(id)+1
  id[new][$1]=new ; id[new][$2]=new
  max[new]=$3 ; line[new]=$0
}

#rerun through id arrays to check for doubles:
FNR!=NR && !b {
  for ( i in id ) {
    for ( j in id[i] ) {
      if ( seen[j] ) {
        for ( k in id[i] ) { id[seen[j]][k]=id[seen[j]][k] }
        delete id[i]
#adjust line deletion selection:
        if (max[seen[j]]>=max[i]) { delete line[i]} else {delete line[seen[j]]}
      }
       else { seen[j]=i }
    }
  }
  delete seen
#adjust UIDs as they may be out of order now:
  for ( i in id ) {++n ; for (j in id[i]) { nid[n][j]=id[i][j] } }
  delete id
#swap line deletion marker from array element to index for better processability
  for (i in line) { line[line[i]]="" ; delete line[i]}
  delete max
#set flag for running this block once only
  b=!b
}

#write to separate files per UID (commented out)
#FNR!=NR {
#  for (i in nid) {
#    if ($1 in nid[i] || $2 in nid[i] ) {print > "person_"i}
#  }
#}
#print lines that have not been selected for deletion
#to STDOUT use the alternative to print it to a separate file
FNR!=NR && ! ($0 in line)
#alternative:
#FNR!=NR && ! ($0 in line) {print > "myoutfile"}


#This is just to print the aID vs UID map
END { print "\n------\nUID vs aID map:\n"
  for (i in nid) {
    print "aIDs for person UID=",i ; b=1
    for (j in nid[i]) {
      if (b) {printf j ; b=0}
      else {printf ","j}
    }
  print ""
  }
}
```

Run as `awk -f script.awk infile infile`, i.e. read the infile twice.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Let me check.